# A holomorphic function which has $|f(z)|>1$ for every $|z|=1$ and $|f(0)|<1$ has a fixed point inside the unit circle

Tags: complex-analysis

Edit: the answer suggested by @ShakedBader posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143903/entire-function-such-that-fz-geq-11z-on-mathbb-c-closure-mathbb) works for this question as well. But I'm curious about the extra assumption here about $|f(0)|$. Does it allow to solve the question using Rouche's lemma?

---

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on a domain which contains the unit circle.

We know that $|f(z)|>1$ for every $|z|=1$, and that $|f(0)|<1$. Show that there exists a point $a\in \mathbb C$, such that $|a|<1$ and $f(a)=a$.

I see that due to continuity, we can find a path in the unit circle which circles zero, and where $|f(z)|=1$ hold for each $z$. But I'm not sure how to proceed. Any clues?

Comment: Can't you use Rouche's theorem to show that f(z) and f(z)-z have the same number of zeros on the interior of the disk ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entire function such that $|f(z)| \geq 11|z|$ on $\mathbb {C}-closure({\mathbb {D}(0, 10))}$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2143903/entire-function-such-that-fz-geq-11z-on-mathbb-c-closure-mathbb)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The condition that $|f(0)|<1$ while $|f(z)|>1$ on the unit circle allows you to conclude by continuity on the closed unit disk that $|f(z)|$ must have a local minimum in the open unit disk.  This minimum must be $0$, or else you would derive a contradiction from the maximum modulus theorem applied to $\dfrac1f$. Thus, you know that $f$ has a zero inside the disk.

You can combine this with [hjr](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/314537/hjr)'s [suggestion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2144073/a-holomorphic-function-which-has-fz1-for-every-z-1-and-f01-has#comment4410228_2144073) to use [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9's_theorem).

Comment: how is applying mmp on $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ deriving a contradiction?

Comment: I can't see really how to reach the contradiction from applying the Maximum Module Theorem to $\frac{1}{f}$? Would it consist of proving $\frac{1}{f}$ can't be constant?
. Could you @Jonas Meyer please detail it a bit more? Thanks for your answer by the way

Comment: @CharlesJA: We know the function is not constant because it has values with modulus <1 and >1. If the minimum is not 0, then the function is nonzero everywhere so 1/f is analytic on the disk (including boundary) and |1/f| has a max at a point interior to the disk, not on the boundary, where |f| has its min.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my writeup of Stein-Shakarchi 3.17 (b) which is essentially the same question for future users stuck on this problem.

(b) If $|f(z)| \geq 1$ whenever $|z|=1$ and there exists a point $z_{0} \in \mathbb{D}$ such $\left|f\left(z_{0}\right)\right|<1$, then the image of $f$ contains the unit disc.

**proof.**
Since $|f|$ is continuous on the compact closed unit disk, the modulus of $f$ attains a minimum on the closed unit disk. By the maximum modulus principle, the minimum must be attained inside the open unit disk since $f(z_0)<1$ but $f(z)\ge 1$ when $|z|=1$.

Now assume that the minimum is attained at $z'\in \mathbb{D}$ and $|f(z')|>0$. Then $f(z)$ is never zero inside $\mathbb{D}$ so $\frac{1}{f(z)}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{D}$. Now we have that $$\frac{1}{|f(z)|} \geq 1 \qquad z\in \mathbb{D}$$ by the maximum modulus principle but this contradicts the existance of the point $1>|f(z')|>0$.

Therefore, there is a point $z\in \mathbb{D}$ at which $f(z)=0$.

Now consider $f(z)-w_0$ for $w_0\in \mathbb{D}$ Since $|f(z)|\geq |-w_0|$ when $z\in \partial \mathbb{D}$ by rouche's theorem, $f(z)-w$ has the same number of zeros as $f$ which has at least one.

Comment: Could you also elaborate on how to complete the a) part of this exercise?